# What does ':' mean in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, grammar

```
 function bid(bytes32 blindBid) public payable validPhase(Phase.Bidding)
    {
        bids[msg.sender] = Bid({
            blindedBid: blindBid,
            deposit: msg.value
        });
    }
```

I just practiced blind auction smart contract example.
But I don't get it `:` meaning in the function.
Is this a comparison with `blindedBid` and `blindBid` ?
But then `deposit: msg.value` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is creating a Bid structure, where: represents =, just like key=value, just like a JSON assignment, so hopefully you get the idea.